# Give somebody a warm welcome or welcome somebody warmly?

Tags: sentence-choice

Suppose you participate in a ceremony in which you do not know the it's establishes. Someone asks you about the way they welcomed you.
Do the following sentences mean the same:

> - They gave us a very warm welcome.
> - They welcomed us very warmly.

Comment: "Warmly welcomed" just sounds strange to me. The first one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, and either is acceptable. I would not find hearing either of these odd. However, it would appear that "warm welcome" is overwhelmingly more common than "welcomed warmly":

[image]

@MorganFR says that "warmly welcomed" sounds strange to him, but it is possible that there is a difference between British and American English in this regard.